# How to bind following HTML markup using Angular 6 reactive form binding?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray, formgroups

I am working on Angular form, please find [this working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jbjigc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html).

I need to bind this form to form group and form array and get out the model and send db for saving the changes. I am getting issue, when same data type come more than one time, dropdown box changes affect to both controls.

Comment: Is your main issue with generating new controls via a Form Array? You are not implementing this correctly, which is why I am asking.

Comment: Please find the updated version, ( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9zezpt?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: My main issue is how do i bind these controls with formArray and get the json object out.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, busy day yesterday. Added an answer. Follow this and it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have not implemented the `FormArray` correctly, as a result you will need to implement this correctly first.

By this, I mean that you have imported the `FormArray` class in your component, but are not using it as a control in your `FormGroup` with controls within the array (I assume you would like to push/pop elements on this `FormArray`), which is it's normal use case.

I have [written an article recently](http://jjburton.com/2018/09/16/angular-6-form-arrays.html) on how to do this, but there is also the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) if you are having any further issues. So in this order, you will need to do the following:

1. Implement the `FormArray` and `FormGroup` into your form;
2. If you require two-way data binding, then use `[(ngModel)]` as well as the Reactive Form binding that comes out of the box.
3. In terms of your issues getting the json object out, this is a simple one; use `{{ yourForm.value | json }}` in your template, which will show your form piped into a json data structure. If there is any issue with the data, you can easily see this here as a debugging method.
4. The `FormControl`, `FormGroup` and `FormArray` will output a clean and valid object, when implemented.
5. Send your json data to the DB.